# Undo a specific file revert in TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

In TortoiseGit commit dialog (before making a commit), I selected a particular file and right click -> Revert

I have changed my mind and would like to "unrevert" this file.

I can't find anything that achieves this. There is no record in the log of this specific file revert and of course because I hadn't committed those changes there is no point to roll back to. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The file should be put into the Windows recycle bin before the changes were undone.

There is no other failsafe active, as the changes were not version controlled (committed).

Also see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-revert.html

Comment: @alistairKane Please accept this answer if it helped you. This is the way to say "Thank you" on StackOverflow.